# Store related items in a single request in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a dynamic form that submits data in a relation:
A Routine can have multiple sections and each section can have multiple exercises.

Here is a example request that gets sent:

```
{"_token":"Z1sF2K5LHU1bsQ4l3JRaOLCTQDmJ47qakigmrfI5","name":"New Routine 111","sections":{"section-1":{"section-name":"Section 1","exercises":{"1":{"name":"Exercise 11"},"2":{"name":"Exercise 12"}}},"section-2":{"section-name":"Section 2","exercises":{"3":{"name":"Exercise 21"},"4":{"name":"Exercise 22"},"5":{"name":"Exercise 23"}}},"section-3":{"section-name":"Section 3","exercises":{"6":{"name":"Exercise 31"},"7":{"name":"Exercise 32"}}}},"submit":"Submit"}
```

So i attempted to foreach through the whol request, but i got a bit stuck to how i can save them all with the required relations:

```
    $routine = new Routine;
    $routine->title = $request->title;
    $routine->user_id = 1;
    $routine->create();
    foreach($data as $item){
        $section = new Section;
        $section->title = $item->title;
        $routine->sections()->create();
        foreach($item['exercises'] as $exercise){
            $section->exercises()->create(['title' => $exercise->title]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```php
foreach($data as $item){
    $section = new Section;
    $section->title = $item->title;
    $section->create();
    foreach($item['exercises'] as $exercise){
        $section->exercises()->create([
              'title' => $exercise->title,
              'user_id' => User::where('token',$token)->first()->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

Dont forget to define the relation exercises() into your Section model.

You can see more info about this in here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: I edited my question with what i tryed with your answer, but i get a new error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value, guess that might be a model issue?

Comment: Even tho i have it set in fillable: protected $fillable = ['name', 'description','user_id'];

Comment: It means that your table has a relationship with User Model and you're not filling that up when you create. You're going to have to get the User using probably the token info and then in your create function, you're going to pass title and user_id aswell. I've edited my answer with the new field

Comment: yes, its a user hasMany routines, but i fill the "user_id" with a static 1 since its only a test environment and i have only 1, if you check my updated quesiton

Comment: Does Section or Exercise models has some relation with User model ? Or just the Routine ?

Comment: Just routine, the rest are related to eachother, like user has many routines, routine has many sections and section belongs to many exercises